# systemd on Arch Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, init, archlinux

So I am experimenting with the use of `systemd` on an Arch Linux machine.

Reading the docs, I see - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Installation

```
add init=/bin/systemd to your kernel cmdline in your bootloader
```

What exactly does this mean?

I am not entirely new to linux but I am having a little trouble understanding how to get this done. Any elaboration much appreciated!

Comment: probably this question should be migrated to serverfault.com

Comment: well.. I see you asked another question there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have arch linux, but I think you should edit your /boot/grub/menu.lst and you'll find a line similar to the following one:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda3 ro 3
```

simply append init=/bin/systemd to the parameters in that line, in this example it would become:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda3 init=/bin/systemd ro 3
```

Reboot.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I am using a virtualized arch linux on linode and I don't see any directories or files inside `/boot` path.

Comment: So, to backtrack on my question a little, how do I know where my `bootloader` is on a given server instance?

Comment: well, I took that path directly from archlinux documentation (italian) https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Init_and_inittab_%28Italiano%29

Comment: what if you look for menu.lst somewhere else? e.g. using: find / -name menu.lst

Comment: Linode.com's default arch linux instance do not have `grub` or `lilo`.  The solution, according to someone on #archlinux irc channel, is to set up pv-grub http://library.linode.com/linode-platform/custom-instances/pv-grub-howto